# Custom GL plugin's GL Impact Line disappearing when the transaction posting flag is "YES"

Tags: plugins, transactions, netsuite, suitescript, accounting

I have created the **custom GL Plugin and configured to the Invoice Transaction.**
Every created **Invoice Transaction is goes for approval process**, once the invoice is approved the **status changed from pending approval to open status.**

when the Invoice Transaction created the Custom GL Impact, working perfectly by creating the Custom GL Lines. Since the Invoice is "Pending Approval State" the Standard and Custom GL Showing correctly and the posting flag is "NO". when the Invoice is approved ,while seeing the GL Impact of the transaction only standard GL Lines are appearing and the Custom GL Lines are disappeared. and posting flag changed to "YES".

My Question is whether the Custom GL Impact plugin will create the custom GL Lines only when the **posting flag is "NO"** or it will remain as it is on the transaction when **posting flag status is both "yes" and "No".**

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite Custom GL Impact will run on on both Non posting and Posting.

Can you provide the code you are using in the Custom GL plugin?  It sounds like a logic issue.  Do you have any logs?

Comment: Hi scheppsr77 ,The scripts logic correct and working fine in administrator user, it's not working correct for different users and while looking the script deplyment, the script is testing mode so it seems to benot working for the different users. I released the script now it is working fine. as you said is correct GL Impact will run on both Posting .and Non Posting. thanks